# wkhtmltoimage works in cli but not browser

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

When I run the script in cli with `$ php test.php` the image creates fine. Below is php script.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Knp\Snappy\Image;

$snappy = new Image(APP_PATH . 'vendor/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64');
$snappy->generateFromHtml('<h1>Bill</h1><p>You owe me money, dude.</p>', APP_PATH . 'test.jpg');
```

When I call the file in the browser I get the following error.

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/tmp/php/domain.dev/knp_snappy545b2790c0b664.98469880.html): failed to open stream:
  No such file or directory in /vagrant/sites/clients/domain.dev/public/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php on line 332
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
  'The file '/vagrant/sites/clients/domain.dev/public/includes/../test.jpg' was not created
  (command: /vagrant/sites/clients/domain.dev/public/includes/../vendor/bin/wkhtmltoimage-amd64 --format 'jpg'
    '/tmp/php/domain.dev/knp_snappy545b2790c0b664.98469880.html'
    '/vagrant/sites/clients/domain.dev/public/includes/../test.jpg').'
in /vagrant/sites/clients/domain.dev/public/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php:276
Stack trace:
  #0 /vagrant/sites/clients/domain.dev/public/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php(132): Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator->checkOutput('/vagrant/sites/...', '/vagrant/sites/...')
  #1 /vagrant/sites/clients/domain.dev/public/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php(142): Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator->generate('/tmp/php/snowma...', '/vagrant/sites/...', Array, false)
  #2 /vagrant/sites/clients/domain.dev/public/test.php(9): Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator->generateFromHtml('
in /vagrant/sites/clients/domain.dev/public/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php on line 276
```

Tried all sorts of vagrant provisioning with different permissions set /tmp file permissions thinking it was there. But what would be different in permissions from cli to browser that could cause this?

Comment: Did you set the permissions on `/vagrant/sites/clients/domain.dev/public/` as well?

Comment: Turned out I had stick permissions set on the site and would not take any other permission no matter what I set.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what do you mean by "stick permissions"?